# Issue getting function result to echo

Tags: php, function, echo

I just started learning more about functions and am currently stuck on one part of them. I am trying to get the result of the function that I set in the return to populate in html in a specific spot.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function profilePic(), 0 passed in /adminNav.php on line 76 and
> exactly 1 expected in /adminNav.php:6 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /adminNav.php(76): profilePic()
>
> ## 1 /admin/project-gallery.php(93): include('pub...')
>
> ## 2 {main}   thrown in /adminNav.php on line 6

Full code:

```
function profilePic($con) {
    try {
        //Profile pic in main
        $sqlProfileImg = "
            SELECT *
            FROM profile_img
            WHERE user_id = ?
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1
            ";
        if ($stmtProfileImg = $con->prepare($sqlProfileImg)) {
            $stmtProfileImg->execute(array($user_id));
            
            $default_profile_img = NULL;
            $userProfilePic = NULL;
            $profilePic = NULL;
            $profilePicRows = $stmtProfileImg->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($profilePicRows as $profilePicRow) {
                $profilePic = $profilePicRow['img'];
                $profilePic = (!empty($profilePic) && $profilePic != 0)? $profilePic : "profile_images/default.jpg"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profilePic) && $profilePic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture";
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        $date = new DateTime();
        file_put_contents('error_log_profile_pic', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . "Error adding attachment: \n" . print_r($e, 1), FILE_APPEND);
        return false;
    }
    return $profilePic;
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="navUserProfilePic" src="<?php profilePic(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a parameter to that function

For example, like this

```
<img id="navUserProfilePic" src="<?php echo profilePic($con); ?>">
                                       ^^^^            ^^^^
```

Your other issue is SCOPE. The function know's nothing about a variable called `$user_id`

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the error, but nothing has outputted unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check the page source? Is nothing output or nothing understandably HTML

Comment: this problem is because he is not echoing any thing in HTML
he should write <?php echo profilePic($con); ?>
but this is not the big problem with the code

Comment: @ahmedgalal Yes just spotted that and corrected the code. Thanks though for the nudge

Comment: `<?=` is a better syntax here. Also it would probably be better to add `global $con;`  than pass the connection into the function every time.

Comment: Still nothing is outputting; not even the alt tags. I changed my html to this `<img id="navUserProfilePic" src="<?php echo profilePic($con, $user_id); ?>>`

Comment: BUT the function has only ONE parameter and that is `$con`

Comment: I changed the function parameter to match.

Comment: Well in that case, is `$user_id` in scope where you call the function?

Answer (score 1):

you are calling

```
<?php profilePic(); ?>
```

put you are expecting

```
<?php profilePic($con); ?>
```

### that's the first problem

why are you sending your connection like that , you should separate your DB class

### Also

if it works you are not echoing your response

Comment: What do you mean "you should separate your DB class"?

Comment: you are sending your connection from your HTML
check this link 
https://laramust.com/post/advance-php-crud-application-with-pdo.html

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out more in-depth. I believe the framework I am using does this already to a certain level. I just haven't added any new public functions in the user class.

Comment: you should study the design without any framework first to understand everything in depth , then get to framework  laravel , symphony or whatever you are using